# System.Timers.Timer invoke WPF component's method

Tags: c#, wpf, events, timer, invoke

I have a class, that is responsible for the logic of a classic snake game logic, that uses `System.Timers.Timer`. Because the exact same class is used for a Windows Forms version of the exact same project, I don't want to change that.

How can I connect a WPF window's method to an event that was designed to be used for WinForms (`ISynchronizeInvoke`)? I'm searching quite a while to achieve this without rewrite my logic class.

Comment: It is pretty unclear how you used ISynchronizeInvoke.  But you could just write a little helper class that implements it and uses Dispatcher to implement the four methods.  It uses the same names, except that InvokeRequired is Dispatcher.CheckAccess().

Comment: this was a missing link for me but may not be enough. I may need to open another question, or refine this one...

Comment: How do I implement the IAsyncResult interface for this use?

Comment: Helper class provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50175680/353147

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Dispatcher` to invoke to the UI thread

```
private void ThreadingTimerTick(object state)// or whatever your method is.
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)delegate()
   {
     // do stuff
   });
}
```