# How to use the ISynchronizeInvoke interface in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, thread-synchronization

I have a component like this and can't change it:

```
public sealed class UFScannerManager
{
    public UFScannerManager(ISynchronizeInvoke synInvoke);
    public ScannerList Scanners { get; }
    public event UFS_SCANNER_PROC ScannerEvent;

    public UFS_STATUS Init();
    public UFS_STATUS Uninit();
    public UFS_STATUS Update();

    [DefaultMember("Item")]
    public sealed class ScannerList
    {
        public ScannerList(UFScannerManager Owner);

        public UFScanner this[int Index] { get; }
        public UFScanner this[string ScannerID] { get; }
        public UFScanner this[IntPtr ScannerHandle] { get; }

        public int Count { get; }
    }
}
```

I want to create an instance of the component like this: `UFScannerManager(this)`, but in WPF I cannot call pass `this` as an argument. Here `this` means the current window form object, the constructor required a `ISynchronizeInvoke sysInvoke` parameter. So when passing `this`, the scanner can be initialized properly in a Windows Form applications. No need to worry about `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface.

```
UFS_STATUS ufs_res;
UFScannerManager ScannerManager;
int nScannerNumber;
ScannerManager = new UFScannerManager(this);
ufs_res = ScannerManager.Init();
nScannerNumber = ScannerManager.Scanners.Count;
```

However, this code does not work in WPF. The problem is this line. The bit it does not like is `this`.

```
ScannerManager = new UFScannerManager(this);
```

When I try to build, I get an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'win_myapp' to 'System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke'

Comment: The advantage of an interface is that you can write an arbitrary class to implement it.  The methods of the interface map easily to your WPF Dispatcher: Invoke => Invoke, BeginInvoke => BeginInvoke, EndInvoke => DispatcherOperation.Wait(), InvokeRequired => CheckAccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF doesn't provide an `ISynchronizeInvoke` implementation like the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class does. So you need to create one.

Fortunately, the WPF's `Dispatcher` class provides all the needed means for that implementation. You just have to create wrappers/adapters for the `Dispatcher` and for the `DispatcherOperation`.

I can give you an idea how to do this. Please note that this code should not be used in a production environment 'as is', because it's simplified and lacks the exception handling.

```
class DispatcherSynchronizeInvoke : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    private readonly Dispatcher dispatcher;

    public DispatcherSynchronizeInvoke(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        // Obtaining a DispatcherOperation instance
        // and wrapping it with our proxy class
        return new DispatcherAsyncResult(
            this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method, DispatcherPriority.Normal, args));
    }

    public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        DispatcherAsyncResult dispatcherResult = result as DispatcherAsyncResult;
        dispatcherResult.Operation.Wait();
        return dispatcherResult.Operation.Result;
    }

    public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        return dispatcher.Invoke(method, DispatcherPriority.Normal, args);
    }

    public bool InvokeRequired => !this.dispatcher.CheckAccess();

    // We also could use the DispatcherOperation.Task directly
    private class DispatcherAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    {      
        private readonly IAsyncResult result;

        public DispatcherAsyncResult(DispatcherOperation operation)
        {
            this.Operation = operation;
            this.result = operation.Task;
        }

        public DispatcherOperation Operation { get; }

        public bool IsCompleted => this.result.IsCompleted;
        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle => this.result.AsyncWaitHandle;
        public object AsyncState => this.result.AsyncState;
        public bool CompletedSynchronously => this.result.CompletedSynchronously;
    }
}
```

Using this custom `ISynchronizeInvoke` implementation, you can instantiate your classes:

```
// Assuming you're calling this inside of a DispatcherObject, e.g. a Window
new UFScannerManager(new DispatcherSynchronizeInvoke(this.Dispatcher));
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @dymanoid's example. Making this into an extension method is preferable.

```
public static class WPFExtensions
{
    public static System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke ISynchronizeInvoke
        (this System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject dispatcher)
    {
        return new DispatcherSynchronizeInvoke(dispatcher.Dispatcher);
    }
}

class DispatcherSynchronizeInvoke : System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    // see dymanoid's answer, you do need one additional line in the internal
    // private class DispatcherAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    // this >>
    //   WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle => this.result.AsyncWaitHandle;
}
```

This works great with the timer class, such that you don't have to marshal the elasped event. From a window you can do:

```
var timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds) 
{ 
    SynchronizingObject = this.ISynchronizeInvoke() 
};
timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
```

Then the timer's elapsed event is on the window's thread.